# Redirecting to another page with jQuery works in IE, but not Firefox, Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({        
        url: "http://www.mysite.com/login.aspx",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(html) {
            $('body').append(html);
        }
    });
</script>
```

It works in IE in that it's successfully redirected but nothing happens in Firefox and Safari.

Why?

Comment: Define "does not work", what happens?

Comment: nothing happens in Firefox but in IE successfully redirected :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('body').html(html)` instead. You should use append with already parsed html (ie. wrapped as jQuery object).

But generally, if you want to do only readirect, and you don't care what url is in location bar - use normal redirect (`document.location = 'url'`).

If you want to replace page content with ajax, it's usually better not to replace whole `body` but only some `container` div inside.

Comment: +1 agree on redirect, and also thanks for explaining the alternative. probably Mike replaces the whole body because after login everything changes, which makes sense, but it probably also mean a traditional redirect is more straightforward.

Comment: In our current system, we wanted to stay on same url every time, so thats why after login we are replacing everything visible (ie. `div#container`) - but there are still few unvisible things outside `container` we want to keep. btw, we still perform full redirect after logout, just for security sake.

Comment: Try removing `context: document.body,`, use html() and not append(), and (as already suggested), not use body, use a container div instead. You can try to remove the fullpath to the script too.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to use an Ajax call to redirect to another page? Why not just use `document.location = 'wherever.htm'`

Comment: Not sure what the 1. poster is trying to do here, but if it's simply redirecting to another page; this is the way to go. Using jQuery, it should read `$(document).location`